# How to load tf.keras model directly from cloud bucket?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-storage

I try to load tf.keras model direcly from cloud bucket but I can't see easy wat to do it.
I would like to load whole model structure not only weights.

I see 3 possible directions:

1. Is posssible to load keras model directly from Google cloud bucket? Command tf.keras.model.load_model('gs://my_bucket/model.h5') doesn't work
2. I tried to use tensorflow.python.lib.ii.file_io but I don't know how to load this as model.
3. I copied model to local directory by gsutil cp command but I don't know how to wait until operation will be complete. tf try to load model before download operation is complete so the errors occurs

I will be thankful for any sugestions.

Peter

Answer (score 4):

1. Load the file from gs storage

```py
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
model_file = file_io.FileIO('gs://mybucket/model.h5', mode='rb')
```

2. Save a temporary copy of the model locally

```py
temp_model_location = './temp_model.h5'
temp_model_file = open(temp_model_location, 'wb')
temp_model_file.write(model_file.read())
temp_model_file.close()
model_file.close()
```

3. Load model saved locally

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(temp_model_location)
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I will tttry work with it.